# sql query for drupal 7 module

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

This query I pulled and worked with from a view.

(it is meant to be handed a node id, and return all nodes that have this node id as a node reference)

```
function jsonview_node_update($node){
  if ($node->type == "company") {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid
              FROM {node} node
              LEFT JOIN field_data_field_campaigncompany ON node.nid = field_data_field_campaigncompany.entity_id AND (field_data_field_campaigncompany.entity_type = node AND field_data_field_campaigncompany.deleted = 0)
              WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (field_data_field_campaigncompany.field_campaigncompany_nid IN  ('".$node->nid."')) AND (node.type IN  ('campaign')) ))";
    $result = db_query($query);
    file_put_contents('/tmp/ref.txt',json_encode($result));
  }
```

is returning

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'node' in 'on clause': SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid FROM {node} node LEFT JOIN field_data_field_campaigncompany ON node.nid = field_data_field_campaigncompany.entity_id AND (field_data_field_campaigncompany.entity_type = node AND field_data_field_campaigncompany.deleted = 0) WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (field_data_field_campaigncompany.field_campaigncompany_nid IN ('14')) AND (node.type IN ('campaign')) )); Array ( ) in jsonview_node_update() (line 224 of /jsonview.module).
```

Not sure what is wrong here..  I've tried out relation and a couple other modules and none really do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> solved:

```
function jsonview_node_update($node){
  if ($node->type == "company") {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT title, nid
              FROM {node} node
              LEFT JOIN field_data_field_campaigncompany ON node.nid = field_data_field_campaigncompany.entity_id AND (field_data_field_campaigncompany.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_campaigncompany.deleted = 0)
              WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (field_data_field_campaigncompany.field_campaigncompany_nid IN  ('".$node->nid."')) AND (node.type IN  ('campaign')) ))";
 //   $query = "SELECT nid, title FROM {node}";
   $result = db_query($query);
  //  $result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node}");
    foreach ($result as $record) {
       file_put_contents('/tmp/ref.txt',json_encode($record),FILE_APPEND);
  // Do something with each $record
}

  }
}
```